# Whats the difference between tf.placeholder() and directly assign a data to variables?

Tags: tensorflow

this is my code and output results

```
import tensorflow as tf
batch_size = 128
sequence_length = 100

batch_size2 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [])
sequence_length2 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [])

_sequence_length1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(batch_size * [sequence_length], dtype=tf.int32)
_sequence_length2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(batch_size2 * [sequence_length2], dtype=tf.int32)

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print('_sequence_length1', session.run(_sequence_length1))
    print('shape of sequence1', _sequence_length1)

    print('_sequence_length2', session.run(_sequence_length2, feed_dict={batch_size2: 128, sequence_length2: 100}))
    print('shape of sequence2', _sequence_length2)
```

here is the results:

```
('_sequence_length1', array([100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
   100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
   100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
   100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
   100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
   100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
   100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
   100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
   100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
   100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100], dtype=int32))
('shape of sequence1', <tf.Tensor 'Const:0' shape=(128,) dtype=int32>)
('_sequence_length2', array([12800], dtype=int32))
('shape of sequence2', <tf.Tensor 'mul:0' shape=(1,) dtype=int32>)
```

I want to using tf.placeholder() to feed different variables to batch_size and sequence_length, But I want the result like the _sequence_length1, I don't know why the shape of _sequence_length2 is (1,), I think the shape of _sequence_length2 is the same as _sequence_length1. so can you tell me why? Much Thanks......

Answer (score 0):

1. `_sequence_length1` - you make `Tensor` from pythons list with 128 elements: `[100, ..., 100]`
2. `_sequence_length2` - is TF operation of multiplication two tensors first `batch_size2` with rank = 0, and second `[sequence_length2]` with rank = 1.

If you want same result as in `_sequence_length1` you can use:

```
_sequence_length2 = tf.tile([sequence_length2], [batch_size2])
```

instead

```
_sequence_length2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(batch_size2 * [sequence_length2], dtype=tf.int32)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem is solved by you method.

Answer (score 0):

It can also using

```
_sequence_length2 = tf.constant(np.full(batch_size, sequence_length2, dtype=np.int32))
```